# MySQL error 1005: Can't create table (lexeme database)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I've designed a MySQL database with 8 tables. I've written the SQL to generate each table with its keys and constraints. But one table always fail on creation, and there's no useful error message that gives a hint about what the problem is. I've described my database on GitHub. Zoom in on the diagram to get an idea how things are connected:

https://github.com/gustafl/Lexeme/wiki/Lexeme-data-model

And here's the code to generate the first 7 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `grammatical_category` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `grammeme` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grammatical_category` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `grammatical_category_fk_idx` (`grammatical_category`),
  CONSTRAINT `grammeme_grammatical_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`grammatical_category`) REFERENCES `grammatical_category` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `lexical_category` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `language` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code_idx` (`code`)
);

CREATE TABLE `lexeme` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lexical_category` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spelling` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pronounciation` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `language_fk_idx` (`language`),
  KEY `lexical_category_fk_idx` (`lexical_category`),
  CONSTRAINT `lexeme_language_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`language`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `lexeme_lexical_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`lexical_category`) REFERENCES `lexical_category` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `inflection` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lexeme` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spelling` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pronounciation` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `lexeme_fk_idx` (`lexeme`),
  CONSTRAINT `inflection_lexeme_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`lexeme`) REFERENCES `lexeme` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `inflection_grammatical_category` (
  `inflection` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `grammatical_category` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`inflection`,`grammatical_category`),
  KEY `inflection_fk_idx` (`inflection`),
  KEY `grammatical_category_fk_idx` (`grammatical_category`),
  CONSTRAINT `inflection_grammatical_category_grammatical_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`grammatical_category`) REFERENCES `grammatical_category` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `inflection_grammatical_category_inflection_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`inflection`) REFERENCES `inflection` (`id`)
);
```

Here's the last table that fails:

```
CREATE TABLE `lexeme_grammatical_category` (
  `lexeme` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `grammatical_category` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lexeme`,`grammatical_category`),
  KEY `lexeme_fk_idx` (`lexeme`),
  KEY `grammatical_category_fk_idx` (`grammatical_category`),
  CONSTRAINT `lexeme_grammatical_category_grammatical_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`grammatical_category`) REFERENCES `grammatical_category` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `lexeme_grammatical_category_lexeme_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`lexeme`) REFERENCES `lexeme` (`id`)
);
```

The **lexeme_grammatical_category** table is identical to **inflection_grammatical_category**, except that "inflection" is replaced with "lexeme" everywhere. I've done a search and replace to be sure.
I've also tried creating **lexeme_grammatical_category** before **inflection_grammatical_category**, but it still fails.

I just can't see what's wrong. I wondered it could be a circular reference problem, because **lexeme** and **inflection** are connected too. But **lexeme_grammatical_category** fails before I create **inflection_grammatical_category**, so I can't see how.

Comment: Executes without any problems on my end.

Comment: It's the weirdest thing: now it works for me too! I've been spending hours trying to track down an imagined error. The database seem to have been corrupted somehow, because it didn't help dropping only the tables. But now, when I dropped the whole database and created it all again, it all worked. Thank you for the attention!